# Explain introductory timing of Action<T> versus Func<T,TResult> Delegates

Tags: .net, delegates

Why was **[Func<T, TResult>(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)** introduced with .NET 3.0 whereas **[Action<T>(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)** with .NET 2.0?

**Edit:** I'm coding a project in .NET 2.0 right now and am missing Func. Although it's easy to roll your own as mentioned in the comments and answers i.e. simple `delegate TResult Func<T,TResult>(T);` I am curious why the timing would be different with two items so similar in nature.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't create your own `MyFunc<T, TResult>`?

Comment: @John S: I already have created my own but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @John Saunders: Except name it `Func<T, TResult>` so the code can seamlessly move to the new framework by excluding the delegate definition.

Comment: I ended up renaming mine `Func1<T, TResult>`, `Func2<T1, T2, TResult>`, etc. to prevent against ambiguity, confusion and naming conflicts when moving to 3.x. The programmers will be forced to explicitly understand it's not the FCL class version and then they will have to decide how to handle it. At that point there's nothing wrong with leaving it in place either.

Comment: @jdk it's far easier to name it identical to the Framework version and put it in a separate namespace. I do this often when adding in functionality to Silverlight that is missing. For example, Einstein.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging interface. When moving to 3.5, you'll get a compiler warning about ambiguity and can just remove the namespace import.

Comment: This is a gripe, not a real question.

Comment: Rather it's a real question that followed a gripe. Really how can it be a gripe when it's easier to roll your own Func<T> than it is to bother posting about it? There has to be some reasoning behind the timing and I'm genuinely interested.  I think Einstein has already alluded to the answer. (BTW What an awesome name - any relation?)

Comment: @jdk: call it `MyFunc<T>` or whatever, and when you get to .NET 3.5, implement it by `Func<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action<T>` and `Predicate<T>` were probably added because of the methods on `List<T>`. It wasn't until C# 3.5 that lambdas were introduced and general delegates like these were particularly convenient.

But as John mentioned, just create your own. There's nothing special about those delegates.